# Can you use sapply with a function with no arguments

Tags: function, loops, arguments, sapply

I am trying to use sapply with a custom function that has no argument; but get an error message.

I wrote the following function:

Coin.Toss <- function() { headortail <- sample(c("head", "tail"), 1, replace =FALSE , prob = c(.65, .35))

if (headortail == "head") 10 else 2 }

...and tried to run a simulation with sapply because the for loop printed each iteration. However, I get the error message below:

earn <- rep(0,50)

sapply(earn, Coin.Toss)

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (X[[i]]).

What do I need to fix?